# Make a DIV cover entire page, but WITHOUT using CSS position

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to make a div with a `background-color` of red to cover my entire page, but I do not want to use CSS `position: absolute`. Here is my example with CSS position:

```
<div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;"></div>
```

CSS position works for the most part, but then I am unable to create more than one of these divs (they overlap or cancel each other out because of `top: 0` and `left: 0`). When you scroll down, I want you to see additional divs.

It would really help if there was a pure CSS solution, but JavaScript and HTML are open to me as well. JUST NO JQUERY.

Comment: You're doing it right, you just set the the next one to `top: 100%` to get it below the first one etc.

Comment: After that, though, top: 200% does not work in Chrome.

Comment: Probably there is something that I don't understand... If you set a div to cover all the page, of course you can have only one ... don't you ?

Comment: Are these going to be the first elements on your page? What about `height: 100vh; width: 100vw;`? [Like this](https://jsfiddle.net/vpmmg6gn/)

Comment: It would also help if I stuck to px instead of % in my case. I'm building an app that only works on a certain screen size, and I am more familiar with px than %.

Comment: My div should cover the entire page, but when you scroll down there should be another, different one. It is essentially three divs that has the same width and height as the window

Comment: These are the first elements in my page.

Comment: Posted one which give the best of 2 worlds ... percent and viewport units

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about using viewport height and viewport width?

I've created an example in [**this JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/vpmmg6gn/).

```css
body, html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

div {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
}

.one {
    background-color: blue;
}

.two {
    background-color: green;
}

.three {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="one"></div>
<div class="two"></div>
<div class="three"></div>
```

Comment: I'm confused as to what vw and vh actually do...

Comment: `vw` is viewport-width, and `vh` is viewport-height. `100vh` translates to "100% of the viewport height" - so it will always take up the entire height of the window, regardless of how you scale the window or which device you're on. As you might expect, you can also do `50vh` to mean 50% of the window height, and so on.

Comment: Thanks, tested and works. Now that I understand this vw and vh concept, I'm probably going to use it a lot more...

Comment: Be sure to take a peak at the [support tables](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units) for it. If you plan on supporting versions of IE previous to IE11, you may want to have a fallback.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make div to occupy entire space use vw and vh

because making div alone height:100% and width:100% would not do it

without using viewport units

check this snippet

```css
div{
 width: 100%;
  height:100%;
  background:red;
   
}

html,body{
  height:100%;
   width:100%;
  }
```

```html
<div ></div>
```

but making html and body to have height and width is a bad idea
so to skip it use view port units

check this with viewport unist

```css
div {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Both of those look exactly the same in my browser, so I'd say setting it to percentage works just fine, and have done so for many years

Comment: yaa fine..but just setting div to occupy 100% width and height you have to make  whole body to have width and height 100%,it is not a good idea to it.preferred way is it use viewport units

Comment: So you think it's better to use units that are only supported in the latest browsers, and that have a multitude of issues in almost all browsers

Comment: no its not what im telling...If you have to support multiple browsers go ahead and use %

Comment: This would help you https://web-design-weekly.com/2014/11/18/viewport-units-vw-vh-vmin-vmax/

Comment: @Geeky vh and vw are supported just fine in all modern browsers as well as IE9, 10, and 11.

Comment: sometimes setting % doesn't work as well as vw and vh. For whatever reason my browser rejects anything bigger than 100%.

Comment: @TylerH - with lots of issues, doesn't work in iframes, doesn't work when zoomed, doesn't work when printed, uses a different name for `vmin` etc.

Comment: @adeneo we are talking only about vh and vw in the context of a div being set to full page height. All the "issues" you mention are not a concern here, and even if they were, that's only for non modern browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Older browsers such as IE7 and 8 could be supported *without* using visual height and width units by using a single absolutely positioned container with inner divs inheriting height and width property values.

### CSS

```
body {
   margin: 0px;  /* optional */
}
#box {
   position:absolute;
   height: 100%;
   min-width: 100%;
}
.page {
   padding: 5px; /* optional */
   height: inherit;
}
```

### HTML

```
    <body>
    <div id="box">

    <div class="page" style="background-color: red">
         <div style="width:25em; background-color: gray">25em</div>
    </div>
    <div class="page" style="background-color: green">2</div>
    <div class="page" style="background-color: white">3</div>

    </div>
    </body>
```

**Update:** the `width` property of the container has been replaced by a `min-width` property, introduced in IE7, to fix an ugly horizontal scrolling issue. Supplying `width` for inner `div` elements was removed as being unnecessary.

Comment: could be useful in some scenarios, but vw and vh idea is easier.

Answer (score 0):

Simply change the `top:` value for each one. The first one would be `0`, the second `100%`, the third `200%`, and so on. Here's a working example:

```html
<div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;background:red;"></div>

<div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute; top: 100%; left: 0; background:blue;"></div>

<div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute; top: 200%; left: 0; background:green;"></div>
```

Comment: For me top: 200% is not working...